# Creating a C++ static wrapper function with specific signature

Tags: c++, templates, function-pointers

I'm having some trouble creating a static wrapper function using template parameters.  I don't want to pass the function directly to the wrapper function, because it needs a specific signature `int (lua_State *)` so that it can be passed into the following function:

```
lua_pushcfunction(L, function);
```

(That's right, I'm going for an auto-generated lua wrapper.)

My first thought is to create a template function with a function pointer as a non-type template argument.

```
template <void(* f)(void)>
int luaCaller(lua_State * _luaState)
{
    f();

    return 0;
}
```

So far, this is looking pretty good.  This function has the proper signature, and calls a function I pass in via template argument.

```
&(luaCaller<myFunc>)
```

My problem arises when I try to wrap this in another function.  Non-type template parameters must be externally linked, and thus the following fails:

```
void pushFunction(lua_State * _luaState, void(* _f)(void))
{
    lua_pushcfunction(_luaState, &(luaCaller<_f>));
}
```

Which makes sense, because the address of the function needs to be known at compile time.  You can't throw in just any pointer and expect the compiler to know which classes to create.  Unfortunately, if I add a function pointer that *is* known at compile time it still fails.  The value of the function pointer is being copied into _a, and therefore _a is still technically not known at compile time.  Because of this, I would expect the following to work:

```
void pushFunction(lua_State * _luaState, void(* const _f)(void))
{
    lua_pushcfunction(_luaState, &(luaCaller<_f>));
}
```

or maybe

```
void pushFunction(lua_State * _luaState, void(* & _f)(void))
{
    lua_pushcfunction(_luaState, &(luaCaller<_f>));
}
```

In the first case, because the value isn't allowed to change, we know that if it is externally linked, it will still technically be externally linked.  In the second case it's being passed in as a reference, which would mean it should have the same linkage, no?  But neither of these attempts work.  Why?  Is it possible to circumvent this somehow?  How can I cleanly auto generate a function that calls another function?

Comment: Just because a parameter is `const` and you're providing a compile-time-constant does _not_ make the parameter a compile-time-constant, sadly.

Comment: That's strange to me.  Is it because you can simply cast to const?  Just thought of that.

Comment: yes, it's because when the compiler compiles `doCaller`, it has no idea what will be passed to it _in the future_.  And other places can and probably do pass run time variables.  There's absolutely no indication to the compiler that the parameter is a compile time constant, there's only an indication that once the function begins you won't modify the parameter.

Comment: Ahh, that's what I was getting at. Is there no way to specify that something is a compile time constant?  I can see now that for the same reason, pass by reference won't work either.

Comment: How is `doCaller(_luaState, a)` superior to `luaCaller<_a>(_luaState)` ?  Just use the second one.

Comment: @roadkillguy Specify a compile time constant by making it a template parameter, `enum`, or `static const int`. `constexpr` in C++11 also works. But none of these can be or apply to function parameters, because every function must be callable at runtime.

Comment: To add to the limitations of Potatoswatter's answer, `enum` and `static const int` can't store function pointers.  You need a template parameter to supply a template parameter.  If you want a runtime choice, you can make a humonguous `switch` statement.

Comment: @BenVoigt The trouble is, in my implementation luaCaller is actually a struct/static function combo.  It has a lot of arguments for variadically wrapping functions of any signature, and it's quite ugly.  `Wrapper<decltype(myFunc), myFunc>::luaCaller` is the furthest I'm able to get it, because of this linkage limitation.  I'm looking for something along the lines of `push<T>(lua_State *, T func)`

Answer (score 1):

The `const` qualifier means you aren't allowed to change something, not that it's a compile-time constant. The initial value of `_a` is determined at runtime when the function is called, and for a `* const &a`, the value can even change at runtime by some external means such as another thread, if the object underlying the reference is not `const`.

To make the fully templated wrapper work, you need to give the compiler enough information to compile a function for each possible template argument, and provide logic to switch among those functions. The template system generates and organizes related functions, but it's not a dynamic dispatcher.

If you can add the function pointer to the `lua_State` object and eliminate the template parameter, that would be one solution.

Your solution would work if make the function pointer a template argument to `doCaller`, but that would defeat its purpose.

Comment: I actually have done what you suggested and added the function pointer to the lua_State. However, I quickly realized I needed a way to store these functions independently of the lua_State, and in my implementation they're actually all of different signatures.  Having a list of int(lua_State*)'s is a convenient way to store them. (I have a lot of variadic templates going on; my example is a simplified case)

Comment: @roadkillguy How does the template know how to call them if they all have different signatures?

Comment: Although, I might be able to use std::bind to bind to a list of simplified ready-to-call functions with the same signature: void(lua_State *).  Upon pushing, these functions would then be associated with a generic lua wrapper function via upvalues.  Though, it appears the question, as it currently stands, is unsolvable.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using a non-type function-template approach in order to bind the secondary function you want to call inside the wrapper-function, you could use a `struct` with a static `luaCaller` method.  That should allow you to maintain the function signature you need for passing `luaCaller` to `lua_pushcfunction`.

So for instance, you could have a struct that looks something like the following:

```
template<void (*f) void>
struct wrapper
{   
    static int luaCaller(lua_State * _luaState)
    {
        f();

        return 0;
    }
};

template<typename Functor>
void doCaller(lua_State * _luaState, Functor wrapper)
{
    Functor::luaCaller(_luaState);
}
```

then call it like:

```
doCaller(&luaState, wrapper<my_func>());
```

Comment: what does `T` do? The template argument here is never used.

Comment: Yeah, that solution wasn't very good ... I think I've come up with a much better one.

Comment: Ah, I see, you're passing the Functor as an argument so you don't need to explicitly specify the template parameter in doCaller. `doCaller<wrapper<my_func>>(luaState)` would work too, yeah?

Comment: I don't see why not ... since you're using a static function, you can always access the function via the type and the scope operator (i.e., `wrapper<my_function>::luaCaller()`).